# How to create installer for my visual basic project with sql server 2008 database?

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, installation

Hi guys I have a visual basic project and I developed it using visual studio 2010 and sql server 2008 for my database.

Now, I want to make an installer that will include my sql server database.

I just used software ADVANCES INSTALLER but it didn't work out.

Help guys. Thanks in advance

Note: Can I make it like InFLOW inventory System installer? It's using also sql server database. Just hoping.

Comment: So you want to package & deploy the .MDFs to an existing SQL Server instance?

Comment: yes... how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Advanced Installer for several years and for deploying database files I use their SQL Databases page. For example, for attaching an MDF file to an SQL instance you can add the MDF file in "Files and Folders" page and use, in SQL Databses page, a script like [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165673%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

You can check out this [tutorial](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-sql.html) to get a starting point about how you can configure the SQL Databses page in Advanced Installer.

Hope this info is useful.

Comment: Thank you so much.! I appreciate your answer.